# Promise proces one by one (Sequential)

Tags: promise, sequential

```
function one_by_one(objects_array, iterator, callback) {
  var start_promise = objects_array.reduce(function (prom, object) {
    return prom.then(function () {
      return iterator(object);
    });
  }, Promise.resolve()); // initial
  if(callback){
    start_promise.then(callback);
  }else{
    return start_promise;
  }
}


one_by_one(requestBodyAll,task);
```

I tried the above code but it processed only the first file. Can someone help please?

- `requestBodyAll` - contains the files list to process. 
  task - function returns promise.

Comment: see **related** links on the right. Also note that to execute promises sequentially you need a array of functions that create promises, not an array of promises.

Answer (score 0):

Looks about right. If the reduction is not progressing past the first file, then it's likely that `task(first_file)` throws. You can find out by logging errors.

Also, you're better off returning a promise from `one_by_one` and not passing a callback.

```
function one_by_one(objects_array, work) {
    return objects_array.reduce(function (prom, object) {
        return prom.then(function() {
            return work(object);
        });
    }, Promise.resolve()); // initial
}

one_by_one(requestBodyAll, someWorkFn)
.then(task)
.catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

`one_by_one()` will (as in the question) deliver the result of `iterator(last_file)` as an argument to `task`. You may prefer to pass nothing, in which case write :

```
.then(function() {
    return task();
})
```

You could immunize the process against errors by catching inside `one_by_one()`.